# How to group by consecutive records SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table and i need to group by consecutive records from [id_2] field:

Dataset:

```
id_1 id_2 datemin            datemax

1    0    2019-01-01 10:14   2019-01-01 15:20
1    1    2019-01-01 15:21   2019-01-01 16:01
1    0    2019-01-01 16:02   2019-01-01 16:08
1    1    2019-01-01 16:09   2019-01-01 16:40
1    1    2019-01-01 16:41   2019-01-01 17:50
1    1    2019-01-01 17:51   2019-01-01 18:36
1    0    2019-01-01 18:36   2019-01-01 19:07
1    1    2019-01-01 19:08   2019-01-01 22:01
1    0    2019-01-01 22:02   2019-01-01 22:47
1    1    2019-01-01 22:47   2019-01-01 23:05
1    0    2019-01-01 23:06   2019-01-01 23:59
```

Expected result:

```
id_1 id_2 datemin            datemax

1    0    2019-01-01 10:14   2019-01-01 15:20
1    1    2019-01-01 15:21   2019-01-01 16:01
1    0    2019-01-01 16:02   2019-01-01 16:08
1    1    2019-01-01 16:09   2019-01-01 18:36
1    0    2019-01-01 18:36   2019-01-01 19:07
1    1    2019-01-01 19:08   2019-01-01 22:01
1    0    2019-01-01 22:02   2019-01-01 22:47
1    1    2019-01-01 22:47   2019-01-01 23:05
1    0    2019-01-01 23:06   2019-01-01 23:59
```

The grouping must be done considering datemin and datemax of each consecutive repeated field [id_2]

I tried other examples but i dont get it at all

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use `Row_Number()`

Comment: Yes, i also tried with LEAD but i cant get it :S

Comment: Show us your attempt. BTW, Give us your sample data via https://dbfiddle.uk/ would very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a gaps-and-islands problem.  If I assume that the time frames tile together (i.e. there are no gaps) -- or that you do not care about gaps -- then the simplest method is probably the different of row numbers:

```
select id_1, id_2, min(date_min), max(date_max)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id_1 order by date_min) as seqnum,
             row_number() over (partition by id_1, id_2 order by date_min) as seqnum_2
      from t
     ) t
group by id_1, id_2, (seqnum - seqnum_2);
```

Why this works is a little tricky to explain.  But if you look at the results of the subquery, you should see how the difference between the two row numbers defines the groups you are looking for.

Answer (score -1):

It is little bit tricky but with combination of lead, lag and rownumber it is achievable.

You need lead and lag to make sure that you are comparing previous with current row and vice versa. Then row number is needed to assign unique numbers so that group by will work for consecutive cases. Moreover, when there is a match I am adding -99 in case statement, so that it will not collide with row number results. by doing this,and with the help of subquery, this should work.

```
with cte as (
select 1 as ID_1, 0 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 10:14:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 15:20:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 1 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 15:21:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 16:01:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 0 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 16:02:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 16:08:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 1 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 16:09:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 16:40:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 1 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 16:41:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 17:50:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 1 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 17:51:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 18:36:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 0 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 18:36:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 19:07:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 1 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 19:08:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 22:01:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 0 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 22:02:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 22:47:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 1 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 22:47:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 23:05:00' as datetime) as Datemax union all 
select 1 as ID_1, 0 as ID_2, cast('2019-01-01 23:06:00' as datetime) Datemin, cast('2019-01-01 23:59:00' as datetime) as Datemax  ) 

--select * from cte; 
select id_1, id_2, min(datemin) min_date, max(datemax) max_date from (
select *, case when lead(id_2) over (order by datemin, datemax) = ID_2
or lag(id_2) over (order by datemin, datemax)  = ID_2  then -99 else row_number () over (order by datemin, datemax) end  as Comparison  from cte) z 
group by id_1, id_2, Comparison 
order by min_date ;
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Adjust it a little it it will be perfect. Pb is if you have another consecutive batch it will merge them because both will be tagged -99

Comment: I can't unvote this answer because the code is such a mess.  But the logic is probably correct and doesn't deserve to be downvoted.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yeah couldn't find a better or cleaner way to achieve this result..but your's is more cleaner and easier to understand

Comment: Also if there has been a down vote, please care to explain as the output being displayed is what was mentioned by user